# Flutter build Fail, gradle :app:debugCompileClasspath

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, flutter-dependencies, flutter-android

### Since yesterday, the Flutter project stopped building for me.

It gives me this error

```
Running "flutter pub get" in promotyflutter...
Launching lib/main_prod.dart on Redmi Note 8 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
   > Problems reading data from Binary store in /tmp/gradle5564899897575971656.bin offset 447048 exists? true

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 29s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
```

---

I have tried many things but nothing has worked so far:

- `flutter clean`, deleted `pubspec.lock` and `flutter pub cache repair` to get rid of cache and reinstall packages but no luck :(
- Flutter downgrade, got the same error
- Fresh reinstall of flutter, same thing
- Fresh git clone of the project and tried running from the prod branch but, nope.
- Tried putting `org.gradle.parallel=false` in gradle settings. No luck :(

I hadn't faced such issues before. In the rare case, `flutter clean` used to do the trick. Any ideas?

---

This is the output of `flutter doctor -v`

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.2.1, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
    • Flutter version 2.2.1 at /home/bipin/snap/flutter/common/flutter
    • Framework revision 02c026b03c (6 weeks ago), 2021-05-27 12:24:44 -0700
    • Engine revision 0fdb562ac8
    • Dart version 2.13.1
                                                                                                                                                                                                  [✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /home/bipin/Android/Sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.3
    • ANDROID_SDK_ROOT = /home/bipin/Android/Sdk
    • Java binary at: /opt/android-studio/jre/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at google-chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    • Android Studio at /opt/android-studio
    • Flutter plugin version 57.0.1
    • Dart plugin version 201.9380
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate Edition (version 2020.3)
    • IntelliJ at /opt/idea-IU-203.7717.56
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart

[✓] VS Code (version 1.57.1)
    • VS Code at /usr/share/code
    • Flutter extension can be installed from:
       https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

[✓] Connected device (2 available)
    • Redmi Note 8 (mobile) • 169612f4 • android-arm64  • Android 10 (API 29)
    • Chrome (web)          • chrome   • web-javascript • Google Chrome 91.0.4472.114

• No issues found!
```

Comment: inside your android flder /gradle/gradle-wrapper.properties use  v 6.7 or highr 
`distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-all.zip`

Comment: @griffins Thanks tried it. But got the same error

Comment: @griffins I also tried with this: `distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.1.1-bin.zip` Also I deleted `.gradle` before running the project. But no luck

Comment: you might have to redownload your android sdk , but first try deleting this folder  `Problems reading data from Binary store in /tmp/gradle5564899897575971656.bin offset 447048 exists? true`

Answer (score -1):

This thing worked for me!.

> distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.7-all.zip

Comment: Hi Pravin, Improve your answer with supporting information for better understanding.